# Population doubled #years

Tags: python-2.7

I have no idea what is wrong in there:

```
current_pop = 7370000000
print "So the current population is", str(current_pop)
doubled_pop = 14740000000
year_1 = 2
year = 0
while current_pop != doubled_pop:
    if current_pop != doubled_pop:
        current_pop = current_pop * 2
        year += 1
    else:
        year += 0
print year
```

I have already tried to like times that current pop by the year_1. But it keeps giving me year = 1

Comment: Please paste your code and do not provide an image

Comment: It keeps giving you a result of `1` because it takes exactly one year for the population to double when the population doubles every year, as your code asserts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your program is that you assume that the population doubles every year! So of course under those conditions the population will double in exactly one year. Thankfully, our situation is not so dire. According to data provided by the World Bank, the annual rate of world population growth was [1.182% in 2015](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.GROW).

Your loop was unnecessarily complicated, but more importantly, your test was wrong. You (and a previous answer) had:

```
while current_pop != doubled_pop:
```

But this test will usually fail, since it is unlikely that the population will grow at a rate that conveniently lands on double the initial population on an exact year division. You need to use an inequality:

```
while current_pop < doubled_pop:
```

Here is a program that works:

```
current_pop = 7370000000
growth_rate = 0.01182
print "So the current population is", str(current_pop)
doubled_pop = 2 * current_pop
year = 0
while current_pop < doubled_pop:
    current_pop = current_pop + (current_pop * growth_rate)
    year += 1

print year
```

And here is the output:

```
So the current population is 7370000000
59
```